# Can't add headers and libs to Yocto SDK

Tags: linux, yocto, yocto-recipe

I am new to Yocto and I am trying to use wsserver recipe to yocto and I am expecting these library headers and lib files will be part of yocto SDK, But I don't see header added in SDK.
**I added this recipe dependency in other recipe and it works fine on final image, But only problem with SDK not having headers and libs**

My current Yocto branch is **Honister**

Here is my recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "wsServer - a very tiny WebSocket server library written in C"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/Theldus/wsServer"
SECTION = "libs"
LICENSE = "GPL-3.0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=985eca66feaf0170850231d4616b3074"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/Theldus/wsServer.git;branch=master;protocol=https"

SRCREV = "476a67448c05ba2057bae43eaa6e704f8b2d6625"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

PROVIDES += "wsserver"

inherit pkgconfig

INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"

do_compile() {
    oe_runmake
}


do_install:append() {
    install -d ${D}${includedir}
    install -m 0644 ${S}/include/* ${D}${includedir}/
    
    install -d ${D}${includedir}/wsserver
    install -m 644 ${S}/include/ws.h ${D}${includedir}/wsserver/ws.h

    install -d ${D}${libdir}
    install -m 0755 ${B}/libws.a ${D}${libdir}/
    #install -m 0755 ${B}/libws.so ${D}${libdir}/
}


FILES:${PN} += " \
    ${datadir}/wsserver \
    ${libdir}/wsserver \
"

FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/libws.a ${includedir}"

FILES:${PN}-dev += " \
    ${libdir}/wsserver/*.la \
"

FILES:${PN}-staticdev += " \
    ${libdir}/wsserver/*.a \
"

FILES:${PN}-dbg += "${libdir}/wsserver/.debug"

IMAGE_INSTALL += " wsserver"
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK += " wsserver"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "nativesdk-wsserver"
BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

Here is the command I tried to build:

```
bitbake firmware-system-image -c populate_sdk
```

I tried these

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += " wsserver"
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK += " wsserver"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "nativesdk-wsserver"

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

and **expecting these headers(ws.h) and libs (libws.a) should be part of SDK**

I expect header file ws.h in this path of my SDK, But Can't find here
#usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-xx-linux-gnueabi/usr/include

My search says one of these IMAGE_INSTALL or TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK should work but Its not.

Thanks for the help.